# How to remove base type from the source code using Roslyn while preserving the newline at the end of the declaration?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I use the following class to remove the base type:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using System.Linq;

namespace CSTool.Rewriters
{
    public class BaseTypeNameRemover : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
    {
        private readonly string m_typeName;
        private readonly string m_baseOldTypeName;
        public bool Changed { get; private set; }

        public BaseTypeNameRemover(string typeName, string baseOldTypeName)
        {
            m_typeName = typeName;
            m_baseOldTypeName = baseOldTypeName;
        }

        public override SyntaxNode VisitBaseList(BaseListSyntax node)
        {
            var trailingTrivia = node.GetTrailingTrivia();
            node = (BaseListSyntax)base.VisitBaseList(node);
            if (!node.ChildNodes().Any())
            {
                return null;
            }
            if (trailingTrivia == null || node.HasTrailingTrivia)
            {
                return node;
            }
            return node.WithTrailingTrivia(trailingTrivia);
        }

        public override SyntaxNode VisitSimpleBaseType(SimpleBaseTypeSyntax node)
        {
            if (node.ToString() != m_baseOldTypeName)
            {
                return node;
            }
            
            Changed = true;
            return null;
        }

        public override SyntaxNode VisitClassDeclaration(ClassDeclarationSyntax node) =>
            node.Parent is BaseTypeDeclarationSyntax || node.Identifier.Text != m_typeName
            ? node
            : base.VisitClassDeclaration(node);

        public override SyntaxNode VisitInterfaceDeclaration(InterfaceDeclarationSyntax node) =>
            node.Parent is BaseTypeDeclarationSyntax || node.Identifier.Text != m_typeName
            ? node
            : base.VisitInterfaceDeclaration(node);
    }
}
```

However, I am unable to preserve the newline after the declaration. Suppose this is the input source code:

```
namespace xyz
{
    interface IInterface : SomeClass
    {
    }
}
```

After running it through my `BaseTypeNameRemover` it becomes:

```
namespace xyz
{
    interface IInterface    {
    }
}
```

But I want to preserve the newline!

In general removing the base type is painful, because I have to override both `VisitSimpleBaseType` and `VisitBaseList`. And I have no idea how to preserve the newline. In short - messy and inaccurate.

What is the proper way to remove the base type cleanly while preserving the newline?

**EDIT 1**

And my code is broken when there are more than 1 base type. I truly do not understand how to do it idiomatically with `CSharpSyntaxRewriter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this as well today, the solution is to modify the identifier of the outer `ClassDeclarationSyntax` to add the trailing trivia from the base list, then set the base list to `null`. Here's an extension method that does the job:

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Removes the specified base type from a Class node.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="node">The <see cref="ClassDeclarationSyntax"/> node that will be modified.</param>
    /// <param name="typeName">The name of the type to be removed.</param>
    /// <returns>An updated <see cref="ClassDeclarationSyntax"/> node.</returns>
    public static ClassDeclarationSyntax RemoveBaseType(this ClassDeclarationSyntax node, string typeName)
    {
        var baseType = node.BaseList?.Types.FirstOrDefault(x => string.Equals(x.ToString(), typeName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        if (baseType == null)
        {
            // Base type not found
            return node;
        }

        var baseTypes = node.BaseList!.Types.Remove(baseType);
        if (baseTypes.Count == 0)
        {
            // No more base implementations, remove the base list entirely
            // Make sure we update the identifier though to include the baselist trailing trivia (typically '\r\n')
            // so the trailing opening brace gets put onto a new line.
            return node
                .WithBaseList(null)
                .WithIdentifier(node.Identifier.WithTrailingTrivia(node.BaseList.GetTrailingTrivia()));
        }
        else
        {
            // Remove the type but retain all remaining types and trivia
            return node.WithBaseList(node.BaseList!.WithTypes(baseTypes));
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the `!.` operator?

Comment: It's an instruction to the C# compiler when using nullable reference types that the property is guaranteed to be non-null. The compiler sometimes misses things and warns you that the property is potentially nullable even though there's a check above that guarantees at that point `BaseList` is non-null. So adding `!.` eliminates the compiler warning. It's only a problem though when you have nullable types enabled.

Answer (score 0):

ִI had enough trying to figure out how to do it. Finally fell back to brute text manipulation:

```
if (node.BaseList == null)
{
    continue;
}

var index = node.BaseList.Types.IndexOf(o => o.ToString() == simpleOldBaseTypeName);
if (index < 0)
{
    continue;
}

var text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
var found = node.BaseList.Types[index];
var start = found.SpanStart;
var end = found.Span.End;
if (node.BaseList.Types.Count == 1 || index > 0)
{
    char stopChar = index == 0 ? ':' : ',';
    while (char.IsWhiteSpace(text[--start]))
    {
    }
    if (text[start] != stopChar)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException($"Failed to parse the base type list in {filePath}");
    }
    while (char.IsWhiteSpace(text[start - 1]))
    {
        --start;
    }
}
else
{
    while (char.IsWhiteSpace(text[end]))
    {
        ++end;
    }
    if (text[end] != ',')
    {
        throw new ApplicationException($"Failed to parse the base type list in {filePath}");
    }
    while (char.IsWhiteSpace(text[++end]))
    {
    }
}

text = text.Remove(start, end - start);
File.WriteAllText(filePath, text);
```

Not ideal, but good enough for me.